# Svelte, JavaScript and JSDoc?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

As far as I know, Svelte is written in JavaScript with JSDoc.

I'd like to learn Svelte and prefer to use JSDoc. When initialising a project with `npm create svelte@latest`, I'm asked the following:

```
◆  Add type checking with TypeScript?
│  ● Yes, using JavaScript with JSDoc comments
│  ○ Yes, using TypeScript syntax
│  ○ No
└
```

My first instict was to select `Yes, using JavaScript with JSDoc comments`, but then I saw the question was `Add type checking with TypeScript?`

What does JavaScript with JSDoc have to do with TypeScript? Why does Svelte offer this weird combination of TypeScript with JavaScript and JSDoc?

And would I have to select No, when I want to use pure JavaScript with JSDoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose "Yes, using JavaScript with JSDoc comments" it will set up:

- A `jsconfig.json` which configures TypeScript to check JS files (`"strict"`, `"allowJs"`, `"checkJs"`, etc.).
- Scripts and dependencies in `package.json` which can be used to check components.
  Type errors in components do *not* cause builds to fail. You can use the scripts `check` or `check:watch` to ensure type safety in component code.

If you select "No" you just get the default checks provided by whatever IDE/extensions you are using.